# git ignore modified file so i can change branch

Tags: git

I created a branch 'users' in which I did a load of changes including one .less file. I had a less compiler open which automatically compiles on save. When I changed to the master branch the .less file got compiled and so my .css file is now different on master. So now I can't merge in users (which includes a commit) or switch back to users branch.

I get the following error:

> ```
> pathspec 'media/less/content/public/template.css' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> ```

Is there anyway I can undo that or ignore the file so I can merge in 'users'?

I tried to checkout the file but it didn't work:

```
git checkout media/less/content/public/template.css
```

Results in

> pathspec 'media/less/content/public/template.css' did not match any
>   file(s) known to git.

Comment: This won't solve your problem directly, but this is precisely why derived files don't belong in source control.  The .css files shouldn't have been checked in to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset one commit back and then see the files that changed, clean up and commit again.

```
git reset HEAD~1
git status # you'll see the files that changed

# probably you need to do this
git checkout media/less/content/public/template.css 
git commit -m "..."
git push -f # to update the last commit
```